# List not correctly append updated dictionary

Tags: python

I make  dictionary in python and append it into a list,after that I updated my keys value and then append it into my list but it remove my previous record and overwrite with the new record. How can I get out of it please guide me.

```
dic={
"name":"karan", 
"password":"karan123"
}

List1=[]

List1.append(dic)

dic.update({"name":"Zakir","password"="Zakir123"

List1.append(dic)
```

Result:

```
[{"name":"zakir","password":"zakir123"},{"name":"zakir","password":"zakir123"},]
```

But I want it like this:

```
[{"name":"karan","password":"laran123"},{"name":"zakir","password":"zakir123"},]
```

Comment: Your list contains a reference to the original object, not a unique copy of the dictionary. You can use deepcopy to append a copy of the dictionary, or just create a new dictionary for each entry that you want to add to the list

Comment: Give you're replacing all the keys in `dic`, why not just assign a brand-new `dict` to it?